# Passing arguments to thread python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I have this method in my class called "interaction":

```
class Interaction:

    def PreparaThreadBrowser(self, User, Password):
       t = ThreadBrowser(args=(User, Password), )
       t.start()
```

that ivokes a thread with User and Pass as parameters.

Then I have the class called "ThreadBrowser" with this "run" method:

```
class ThreadBrowser(threading.Thread):

    def run (self, user, password):

        self.User = user
        self.Pass = password
        print(self.User, self.Pass)
```

but it turns out that I'm certainly struggling sending the arguments to the thread function because it gives an execution error:

`TypeError: run() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'user' and 'password'`

Any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Could you fix your indentation and add the code where you actually call `ThreadBrowser.run()`?

Comment: @Primusa `Thread.run` is automatically invoked by [`Thread.start`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `args` constructor argument can't provide additional arguments to `run`. It provides the arguments to *target*, which you aren't specifying. Specifically:

- the default implementation of `run()` invokes `self.target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)`, where `_args` and `_kwargs` are provided by the constructor, and default to empty tuple and dict respectively.
- by implementing `run` you opted out of Python invoking `target(*args)` automatically. It is then up to your code to store the state that your `run` will pick up. The idiomatic option is to store it in the constructor, much like your `run` method does now.

For example:

```
class ThreadBrowser(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        super(ThreadBrowser, self).__init__()
        self.User = user
        self.Pass = password

    def run(self):
        print(self.User, self.Pass)
```

The `ThreadBrowser` can then be constructed naturally as `ThreadBrowser(username, password)` and started with `t.start()` as before.

Comment: That makes sense however it's giving a compiling error:
https://imgur.com/a/F0SPLME

Comment: @GonçaloBaptista The error appears like an unrelated issue of mixing tabs and spaces. The code in the answer consistently uses spaces; did you copy/paste it?

Comment: yes, didn't know couldn't copy paste. Sorry. It worked :D Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Run takes 2 arguments user, pass

```
import threading



class Interaction:
    def PreparaThreadBrowser(self, User, Password):
        t = ThreadBrowser(args=(User, Pass), )
        t.start()



class ThreadBrowser(threading.Thread):

    def run (self, user, password):
        self.User = user
        self.Pass = password
        print(self.User, self.Pass)



t = ThreadBrowser()
t.run("user", "pass")
```

Comment: If i use like you told me too, the paramaters arrive correctly in the run method but the thread isn't invoked !

Comment: Invoking `run` directly is wrong, the thread must always be invoked using the `start()` method.